# array_combine() on each subarrays of two multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-combine

In PHP, I have 2 multidimensional arrays. such as:

**array 1:**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]];
```

**Array 2:**

```
[[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
```

I need to combine these two arrays.

I need the first array's subarray values to be the keys of resulting multidimensional's subarrays and the second array's subarray values to be the values of resulting multidimensional's subarray.

I need the output like this format:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    1 => 4,
    2 => 5,
    3 => 6,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    1 => 7,
    2 => 8,
    3 => 9,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try with:

```
$length = sizeof($arrayA);
$output = array();

for ( $i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i ) {
  $output[] = array_combine($arrayA[$i], $arrayB[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be concisely accomplished by calling `array_combine()` while simultaneously iterating (mapping) the two equal-length arrays with equal-length subarrays.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/TC0mg))

```
$arr1 = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]];
$arr2 = [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
var_export(
    array_map('array_combine', $arr1, $arr2)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    1 => 4,
    2 => 5,
    3 => 6,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    1 => 7,
    2 => 8,
    3 => 9,
  ),
)
```